# componentDidUpdate scroll to bottom when item is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a list, I want to scroll to the bottom, I have my component coded like this

```
class Msg extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate() {

        if(this.container){
            this.container.scrollTop = this.container.scrollHeight
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div ref={elem = this.container = elem}>
                <Item />
                <Item />
                <Item />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

It worked. But the problem is it scroll every time when the component rerender. Msg has many children component, trigger the state of child component will cause Msg component to render again, how to solve this problem?

To explain it like a normal user:

User scrolls up the list, then click on dropdown somewhere, the componentDidUpdate triggered, caused scrolled to bottom.

Comment: So, when do you want it to scroll down... when a new item is added? I would suggest adding a new button to the UX that allows the user to scroll down when needed, instead.

Comment: @camou in whatssap's msg, did you see a button to do that?

Comment: No, but WhatsApp does not force me to go down when I'm scrolling up on iOS9.2. So, when do you want to scroll down, when there is a new message or when the user stops scrolling up within the last few seconds?

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the bottom first time when the component is rendered you should use `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

If you want the list to scroll every time an element is added, you can use `componentDidUpdate` hook like you are using now, but instead of manipulating scrolltop every time, check if the number of items you are rendering has changed. Now you are setting the scroll top every time the component updates.

`componentDidUpdate` gets both previous props and previous state as parameter, so you can write something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.items.length > prevProps.items.length) {
        this.refs.container.scrollTop = this.refs.container.scrollHeight;
    }
}
```

Here's a good reference for reacts lifecycle hooks: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Comment: put this `this.refs.container.scrollTop = this.refs.container.scrollHeight;` in componentDidMount it won't work

Comment: What are you rendering in your list? E.g. with images the scrollHeight might still be zero during componentDidMount because the images have not yet loaded and don't take space in the container.

Comment: images and text.

Comment: And do you get some scroll height on in the componentDidMount or just zero? Do you get something if you use setTimeout to delay getting the scrollHeight? (just for debug. Hacking the scroll without timeout will likely lead to more trouble)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this
add a blank div at end of list

`<div ref="blankdiv"></div>`

then in every `componentDidMount` scroll this div in screen

`this.refs.blankdiv.scrollIntoView()`